# How to recover iPhone videos deleted through Image Capture on Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, data-recovery, image-capture

I accidentally deleted some videos on an iPhone through Image Capture and there is no back up.

- iPhone Xs
- iOS 16.1.1
- macOS Ventura 13.5.2
- Image Capture 8.0

They are not in the 'Recently Deleted' folder on iPhone. They did not show up when scanning on third party recovery apps on Mac (Mac  FoneLab, UltData).

How do I recover them?

Answer (score 0):

There is no viable way to perform file undeletion on an iPhone itself or from Image Capture , sadly - all of the apps I’ve seen to recover files are almost categorically “a waste of time”, but perhaps you’ll have better luck if you’re not writing any new data and some more clever tool can scan of free space on the device before it gets overwritten? (Assuming that hasn’t happened already.)

- https://www.cleverfiles.com/iphone-data-recovery.html

Depending on how valuable the files are, getting a quote from professional data recovery services might be advisable before you use the device or power it on again to preserve the state and maximize your window of success.

The older file systems such as HFS and such were more amenable to recovery and the newer APFS ones are not. Backup regimen is very important due to technical and architectural decisions baked in to the hardware and software now.